# SQLITE query, if last row matches criteria, check row preceding it matches different criteria

Tags: sqlite

I'm finding it hard to get my head around this problem, and I couldn't find any answers to this specific problem anywhere:

Say I have a table like this, I'm just using fruit as an example:

```
Fruit | Date | Value
=================================
Apple |    1 | other_random_value
Apple |    2 | some_value_1
Apple |    3 | some_value_2
Pear  |    1 | other_random_value
Pear  |    2 | unexpected_value_1
Pear  |    3 | some_value_2
```

Everything will be ordered by Fruit, then Date.

Basically, if the last row (for each fruit) is some_value_2, but the one preceding it is not some_value_1, I want to match just those fruits (i.e. in this case, Pear).

So, some_value_2 I always expect to come after a row with a certain value for that particular fruit, and if it doesn't I want to flag errors against those particular fruits. It would also be nice to match cases where nothing precedes some_value_2 as well, though if this is too complicated I could match it seperately and just check that some_value_2 is not the first row, which I don't imagine would be a difficult query.

**EDIT:** Also, being able to match any consecutive rows where the preceding value is unexpected would be nice, though I mainly care about the last 2 rows. So if being able to match all consecutive rows results in a simpler and better performing query, then I might go with that. I'm going to be doing an INSERT at the same time (into an alert table), so if I could flag it as an ERROR if it's the last two rows and a WARNING if it's not, that would be really nifty. Though I wouldn't know where to start with writing a query that does that. Also having a query that performs well is a must, as I will be using this across a large dataset.

**EDIT:**

This is what I used in the end, it's quite slow, but if I index Date, it's not so bad:

```
SELECT c.Id AS CId, c.Fruit AS CFruit,
       c.Date AS CDate, c.Value AS CValue,
       (SELECT Id
        FROM fruits
        WHERE Fruit = c.Fruit
        AND Date >= c.Date
        AND Id > c.Id
        ORDER BY Date, Id) AS NId, n.Fruit AS NFruit,
       n.Date AS NDate, n.Value AS NValue
FROM fruits AS c
JOIN fruits AS n ON n.Id = NId
ORDER BY c.Date, c.Id
```

I might try Joachim's method again at some point, as I realised I'm getting a lot of results I don't really care much about. Or I might even try incorporating the two somehow and delegate to INFO/ERROR as appropriate...

---

**Solved:** I used the same SELECT statement that I used to get NId, and used SELECT COUNT(*) instead of SELECT Id. This told me the number of results after the current one. Then I just used a CASE operator to turn it into a boolean field called Latest :). So I effectively combined Nicolas' and Joachim's methods. Performance still seems OK, probably because SQLite caches the results.

Comment: Why do you assume that there is an inherent order to the table? The first rule of SQL is that table rows only have such order as _your query_ tells them to have.

Comment: I'm going to be ordering by date, I didn't make that particularly clear. I've re-worded it.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is (as far as I know) a bit low on efficient operators for this, so this is the best I can come up with for now :)

```
SELECT Fruit FROM fruits
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruits f 
        WHERE f.fruit=fruits.fruit 
          AND f.date > fruits.date ) = 1
  AND fruits.value <> 'some_value_1'
INTERSECT 
SELECT Fruit FROM fruits
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruits f 
        WHERE f.fruit=fruits.fruit 
          AND f.date > fruits.date ) = 0
  AND fruits.value = 'some_value_2'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d6637/9).

Comment: Seems to be working great, thanks. Also seems fast. I'm still testing it, my actual database isn't as simple as the one above, but hopefully I'll be able to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my actual database, I have entries that have the same date, so I use Id (which is an auto-incrementing field) to also check the order. But it's really slow if I check against Id rather than Date.

I wonder if using GROUP BY and somehow skimming of the last and second-from-last rows could be faster? This was the approach I was trying first, but I couldn't figure it out.

If I figure out a more efficient query I will post it here. This is a good starting point.

Comment: In other queries where I show these entries sorted, I use Date and Id as my ORDER BY, because I favour the date over the order it was added to the database. If I concatenate the date and ID before I order by it, this is faster, but seems like quite a weird way to get around the speed issue, I'm sure there must be a better way.

Comment: @user989266 If date is fast, and id is slow, it sounds like an indexing problem. Do you have any index on id? Any existing index on Date?

Comment: @user989266 Should be, just asking to be sure. About the query, it can be rewritten as a rather cumbersome join, but I doubt performance would be better. I'd run `EXPLAIN` on the actual query in your database and see if I could figure out why it won't hit indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm too thick to understand the output :(

Comment: Hi, indexing Date sped things up quite a bit, because ordering by Date only was quite fast, I assumed I didn't need to index it. But this turned out to be the main bottleneck.

Comment: @user989266 Glad you found it, very hard to debug indexes without seeing the actual schema/explain :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really want to clutter up this page with my schema / explain output.

Answer (score 0):

I named the table `fruits`. This query gets you the preceding date for a ‘key‘ (fruit + date)

```
select fruit, date, value currvalue,
      (select max(date) precedingDate 
         from fruits p 
         where p.fruit = c.fruit 
         and p.date < c.date) precedingdate 
 from fruits c ;
```

From there we can get the precedent value for each key

```
select f1.*, precedingdate, f2.value precedingvalue
from
    fruits f1 join
    (select fruit, date, value,
          (select max(date) precedingDate 
             from fruits p 
             where p.fruit = c.fruit 
             and p.date < c.date) precedingdate 
     from fruits c) f2 
   on f1.fruit = f2.fruit and f1.date = precedingdate ;
```

For all the rows that have a previous row, you get both the current and preceding date and the current and preceding value.

**Edit :** we add an id used to choose when there are several identical previous date (see comment below)

I will be using intermediate views for the sake of clarity but you could write one big query.

As before, what's the previous date :

```
create view VFruitsWithPreviousDate
as select fruit, date, value, id,
 (select max(date) 
         from fruits p 
         where p.fruit = c.fruit 
         and p.date < c.date) previousdate 
 from fruits c  ;
```

What's the previous id :

```
create view  VFruitsWithPreviousId
as select fruit, date, value, 
    (select max(id) 
    from fruits f
    where v.fruit = f.fruit AND 
       v.previousdate = f.date) previousID
from VFruitsWithPreviousDate v ;
```

A query for all consecutive rows :

```
select f.*, v.value
from fruits f
join VFruitsWithPreviousId v on  f.id = v.previousid ;
```

You can then  add the condition `WHERE f.Value = 'some_value_2' AND v.value != 'some_value_1'`

Comment: Hi, this works really well, but causes problems in my database when two records have the same date. I'd also like to sort by Id as well, where Id is an auto-incrementing field. E.g. if there are 2 dates that are the same, I'd like to favour the one with the higher Id. Do you know how I could incorporate that into this query? I really should've mentioned the Id in the original question, but didn't realise it would be difficult to adapt it to suit my database.

Comment: I tried the new query that takes in account the ID, but if all the dates are set equally, nothing is returned by the query. I made an SQL Fiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3bb0e/2. This is a really tricky problem. :\